# Passing JQuery var to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass 3 variables that look like this

```
var location = document.location.pathname;
var search = document.location.search;
var referrer = document.referrer;
```

Into a PHP file that I can eventually use to send emails, I have never used AJAX before but know that you could use it to achieve this.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you know that jQuery has a tutorial about Ajax? http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ . [MDN has a tutorial as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). That's what tutorials are there for: Teaching you about something you are not familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Ajax POST method can help you here. Here's an example.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {location: location, search: search, referrer: referrer},
            success: function(response){                    
                //do something
            }
        })//ajax end
```

Now in ajax.php, you can receive the values via `$_POST`.

PHP Receiving(ajax.php).

```
var_dump($_POST['location']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {'location': location,
            'search': search,
            'referrer': referrer
        },
        url: "Here the path to your php-file",
        success: function (data) {
            Here you could react on any 
        }
    });
```

In the php file you receive those data by Post and can handle them.